# Local font not loading with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css, vite

I've been unable to load a local font for my website using tailwind css. I have checked using the network tab on google chrome's developer tools and the font does not appear to be loading. I think it is unable to locate the font file itself but I haven't been able to figure out why because there aren't any error messages or anything.

My file structure:

- project

  - src

    - fonts

      - Metropolis-Regular.otf
    - styles.css
  - vite.config.ts
  - tailwind.config.ts

My vite.config.ts file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: '@', replacement: './src' }]
    }
})
```

My styles.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Metropolis";
        src: url("/fonts/Metropolis-Regular.otf") format("otf");
    }
}
```

My tailwind.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
      "./index.html",
      "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
    ],
    theme: {
      extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            "metropolis": ["Metropolis", "serif"]
        },
        colors: {
            "white": "#F9F5EB",
            "grey": "#E4DCCF",
            "red": "#EA5455",
            "blue": "#002B5B",
            "lightblue": "#3F72AF"
        }
      },
    },
    safelist: [
        "h-[6rem]",
        "h-[7.5rem]",
        "h-[8rem]",
        "bottom-[0.6rem]",
        "bottom-[0.75rem]",
        "bottom-[0.8rem]"
    ],
    plugins: [],
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
src: url("/fonts/Metropolis-Regular.otf") format("otf");
```

to

```
src: url("../fonts/Metropolis-Regular.otf") format('opentype');
```

also, should there be quotations around metropolis in the tailwind config file?

Comment: Unfortunately, this still did not work as it was still showing the default font. Also, the quotation marks around metropolis don't seem to affect anything since my components were still able to use it when I tested using the tailwind's built in fonts.

Comment: I think the path is correct "fonts/Metropolis-Regular.otf" but the format identifier must be 'opentype' as described by Manas. Most modern browsers also allow omitting the format.